# autocalculate total value of items in listview when removing item using c#

Tags: c#, listview

I'm using a listview as a shopping cart.  I need to know how to recalculate the total value of the cart when I remove an item.

Here is my code for adding to listview;

```
private void btnACart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int value = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < lvCart.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        value += int.Parse(lvCart.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text);
    }

    rtbTcost.Text = value.ToString();
}
```

Here is my code for removing items:

```
private void btnRemoveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int total = 0;
    foreach (ListViewItem item in lvCart.Items)
    {
        if (lvCart.Items[0].Selected)
        {
            lvCart.Items.Remove(lvCart.SelectedItems[0]);
            total += Convert.ToInt32(item.SubItems[1].Text);
        }
    }

    rtbTcost.Text = total.ToString();
}
```

I want to recalculate the total value of items an item is removed. How should I do that?

Comment: Could you, please, clarify what total you're asking. For me it did not open up, while reading the question.

Comment: I want the listview to act as a cart. I'm trying to get the total price of every item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

On the form level declare

```
private int _listTotal;
```

Adding - I think here you have some problems because you should add to total when you add the item

```
private void btnACart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int value = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < lvCart.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        value += int.Parse(lvCart.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text);
    }
    // how about lvCart.Items.Add(<myVal>)...???
    _listTotal += value; // and here add myVal
    rtbTcost.Text = _listTotal.ToString();
}
```

Then when removing - you don't want to use any "for-loops" on mutating collection. But "while" works perfectly on mutations

```
private void btnRemoveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int totalRemoved = 0;
    while (lvCart.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        totalRemoved += Convert.ToInt32(lvCart.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text);
        lvCart.Items.Remove(lvCart.SelectedItems[0]);
    } 
    _listTotal -= totalRemoved;
    rtbTcost.Text = _listTotal.ToString

}
```

Not tested but should work

Comment: thanks for the help sir. Not really that accurate but it worked fine.

Comment: Excuse me sir regarding to this program. My problem in the code you gave to me is that the every time I remove the item the value that it is removing is the 1st value added into the listview @T.S.

Comment: @bluffer I just tested it - it works fine. I have list view with  `_l.MultiSelect = true;`. I've added 10 items, selected 3 of them, for example items, 2,5,8. And they got removed perfectly by ` while (_l.SelectedItems.Count > 0) { _l.Items.Remove(_l.SelectedItems[0]);}` I see no problem. You need to actually click and select the item before removing it.

Comment: thanks again sir hahaha. I tried using for loop and combined your code. But it now works fine thank you very much!!!!

Comment: I warned you - don't use for-loop for mutating collections!! :o))

Comment: Excuse sir I have another problem when adding a new item. I added a new column which is "Number of Items". I'm asking how can I calculate the product for each item.

Comment: you would probably have to calculate as follows `value += int.Parse(lvCart.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text) * int.Parse(lvCart.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text);` - multiply item price by num of items

Comment: Excuse me sir I have one more bothering question. In adding item I want to check if item is already in listview. If item does exist don't add.. Waitin for your reply.. Thank you

Comment: Just iterate your list and compare the existing values, and if you find one, don't add the new item

Comment: `bool alreadyInList; foreach (var item in lv.Items) {  if (item.text == newValue) alreadyInList=true; break;} if (!alreadyInList) lv.items.Add(newValue);`

Comment: Sorry sir at the moment I can't I have low reputation... :3

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the same list in foreach.

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in lvCart.Items)
{
    if (lvCart.Items[0].Selected)
    {
        lvCart.Items.Remove(lvCart.SelectedItems[0]);
        total += Convert.ToInt32(item.SubItems[1].Text);
    }
}
```

The solution is create duplicate list and change it:

```
var newList = lvCart;

foreach (ListViewItem item in lvCart.Items)
{
    if (lvCart.Items[0].Selected)
    {
        newList.Items.Remove(lvCart.SelectedItems[0]);
        total += Convert.ToInt32(item.SubItems[1].Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnRemoveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int total = 0;
    foreach (ListViewItem item in lvCart.Items)
    {
       if (lvCart.Items[0].Selected)
        {
            total+=(int)lvCart.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;//Add to total while romving
           lvCart.Items.Remove(lvCart.SelectedItems[0]);
           //total += Convert.ToInt32(item.SubItems[1].Text);
        }
    }

      rtbTcost.Text = total.ToString();
   }
```